# Silverlight File upload to the remote server error

Tags: silverlight, file-upload

I need to upload a file to the remote server in silverlight project.

Following is my code. I want to upload a PDF file.

```
public bool UploadHelpDocument(string FileName, byte[] ms)
    {
        if (FileName != null)
        {
            if (ms.Length > 0)
            {
                FileUpload fu = new FileUpload();
                string HelpDocPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HelpDocs"];
                if (!Directory.Exists(HelpDocPath))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(HelpDocPath);
                }
                if(fu.saveFileChunk(FileName, ms, HelpDocPath, 0) == true)
                {
                    string fileURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HelpDocs"] + FileName;
                    byte[] localHelpfile = readLocalShapeFile(fileURL);

                    string sURL = "http://serverpath";

                    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(sURL);

                    request.ContentType = "application/ms-word";
                    request.Method = "PUT";
                    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("", "");

                    Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
                    requestStream.Write(localHelpfile, 0, localHelpfile.Length);

                    requestStream.Close();

                    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I am getting an error at
**WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();**
this line. It say **The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.**

What might be the reason of this error?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Do you want send WebRequest from Silverlight app?

- If no, I think that destination server can't handle this request method or type of file. You can try change ContentType like:

this:

```
request.ContentType = "text/msword";
```

or

```
request.ContentType = "text/plain";
```

If this not help, I think that server does not handle PUT method, You need to research configuration of destination server.

- If yes, it is look like crossdomain issue. You can use one of two approaches.

1) If you have access to destination server, You can create crossdomain.xml or/and clientaccesspolicy.xml on them like this:

**clientaccesspolicy.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from http-request-headers="*">
        <domain uri="*"/>
      </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

**crossdomain.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

You can read more:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955%28VS.95%29.aspx

http://www.leggetter.co.uk/2008/10/24/how-to-make-a-cross-domain-web-request-with-silverlight-2.html

2) If You have not access to destination server (worse news). You need to create WebRequest bypass local serwer. The best approach is by integrate Silverlight with WCF RIA Service. At first you need to send file by RIA Service to local server and next from server you need to send WebRequest with this file to destination server unlimited.

```
public void RIAHandleFile(byte[] file)
{
    //(...)
    requestStream.Write(file, 0, file.Length);
    //(...)
}
```

In Silverlight invoke this function like

```
byte[] file;
InvokeOperation ria = domainContext.RIAHandleFile(file)
```

Comment: There is example project with WCF RIA Service: 

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlight/Getting-Started-WCF-RIA-1469cbe2